# How many pre-sale addresses are there?

Tags: presale

How many addresses did Ethereum have when it launched? In other words, how many pre-sale addresses are there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**8893**

I got this number using the genesis block that I created myself using the instructions in this [blog post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/07/27/final-steps/). I generated the JSON file, imported it into a NodeJS REPL and queried the length of the `alloc` property. This list includes all presale addresses and their balances at the time of the network launch.