# Is there an API that can find all the ERC20 token icons?

Tags: erc-20

I'm trying to find icons for all ERC20 tokens, does any API provide that information ?.

Comment: what does you mean? if want to know how to add icon to your ERC20 tokens i can help you.

Comment: I need just gather all ERC20 token logos, icon, image whatever you call it in .png or .ico or whatever available format available. Parse etherescan and pull images as an option, but i'm looking for more sufficient way by calling API.

Comment: Token Icons is something specifically from Etherscan, you should check their API.

Comment: have a look at the cryptocompare api https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#requests they provide logos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. Now i can add and query contract image from here https://github.com/trustwallet/assets

Answer (score 4):

Possibly a bit off-topic...

What are you considering a token? [Etherscan says there are 19765 ERC-20-compliant tokens at present](https://etherscan.io/tokens). I imagine you're not bothered about most of them.

To weed out tokens you're unlikely to care about, you could qualify tokens based on their inclusion on exchanges. As a way to aggregate data across exchanges, you could use data from somewhere like CoinMarketCap. Their API doesn't do what you're after. (And neither does Etherscan's. It also appears that Etherscan's list view only lists the [top 50 tokens](https://etherscan.io/tokens), with no logical way to list further.)

There's a script in a previous answer, [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/31925/52), that puts the current number of Ethereum-based tokens known about by CoinMarketCap at 349. It doesn't distinguish between ERC-20 and non-ERC-20 tokens, though.

Looking at the page source for their token list, they seem to use an [image sprite](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) containing all of the symbols (to help load pages more quickly).

[image: CoinMarketCap image sprite]

Any script you use to pull them out of the image would need the offsets contained in the associated CSS.

Failing that, someone else may just know of a decent API :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is this project:

https://github.com/ethereum-lists/tokens

They list a great number of tokens, for many blockchains.
Each token json provide a great deal of information, like social networks, website, logo img, and much more.

Take a look.